# How does DNA shape a living organism?

Tags: genetics, dna, reproduction, gene, dna-replication

I'm haven't studied biology so excuse me if I'm getting something wrong.
I'm trying to understand how the DNA from a sperm and egg cause the egg too multiply and form a perticular shape (shape of a fetus). Or in case of plants how does dna in a seed cause the sapling to grow into a plant of perticular shape and size?
I mean how does DNA cause the cell to multiply and grow into hands and legs and heads of a certain shape and size in animals. Or to stems, branches and leaves in plants? How does DNA shape a living organism?

Comment: Answer to this question can fill (and has filled) multiple textbooks. Entire branch of biology - developmental genetics - studies exactly this. If you are interested I recomend starting with some introductory book about genetics. If you don't significantly narrow your question I doubt someone will be able to answer you here.